# Search multidimensional array containing associative and indexed levels for a value then get a related element's value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, traversal

I am trying to extract a value from an array by searching by another value.
I have the `uri` value and I require the `playcount` value that corresponds with the uri.

What is the best approach to traverse this multi-level array and return the desired data?

My current code:

```
$decoded = json_decode($response, true);
$trackids = 'spotify:track:'. $trackid .'';

$key = array_search($trackids, array_column($decoded, 'playcount'));
$result = $decoded[$key]['playcount'];

echo "Result: ";
echo $result;
```

I think it is incomplete and not sure how to proceed from there as it doesn't work.

The `$decoded` array:

```
$decoded = [
    'success' => 1,
    'data' => [
        'uri' => 'spotify:album:3T4tUhGYeRNVUGevb0wThu',
        'name' => '÷ (Deluxe)',
        'cover' => [
            'uri' => 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02ba5db46f4b838ef6027e6f96'
        ],
        'year' => 2017,
        'track_count' => 16,
        'discs' => [
            [
                'number' => 1,
                'name' => null,
                'tracks' => [
                    [
                        'uri' => 'spotify:track:7oolFzHipTMg2nL7shhdz2',
                        'playcount' => 181540969,
                        'name' => 'Eraser',
                        'popularity' => 63,
                        'number' => 1,
                        'duration' => 227426,
                        'explicit' => null,
                        'playable' => 1,
                        'artists' => [
                            [
                                'name' => 'Ed Sheeran',
                                'uri' => 'spotify:artist:6eUKZXaKkcviH0Ku9w2n3V',
                                'image' => [
                                    'uri' => 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000517412a2ef08d00dd7451a6dbed6'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'uri' => 'spotify:track:6PCUP3dWmTjcTtXY02oFdT',
                        'playcount' => 966197832,
                        'name' => 'Castle on the Hill',
                        'popularity' => 79,
                        'number' => 2,
                        'duration' => 261153,
                        'explicit' => null,
                        'playable' => 1,
                        'artists' => [
                            [
                                'name' => 'Ed Sheeran',
                                'uri' => 'spotify:artist:6eUKZXaKkcviH0Ku9w2n3V',
                                'image' => [
                                    'uri' => 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000517412a2ef08d00dd7451a6dbed6'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: You should share an example of the original json. Because nobody is sure what array is here but you.

Answer (score 0):

`$key = array_search($trackids, array_column($decoded, 'playcount'));` in this line, you make two mistake. First, there is no column like playcount in **$decode** array. Second, you are searching with `uri` key, not `playcount` key. There is one more thing, discs key and track inside discs key, both are multidimensional array. So if you want to fetch the exact value, This query will be,

```
$decoded = array_map(function($x) {
    return array_column($x, 'url');
}, array_column($decoded['data']['discs'], 'tracks')); 
$decoded = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $decoded);

$key = array_search($trackids, $decoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you need to dig down deeper into the array structure to search for the tracks within each disc.

```php
$decoded = json_decode($response, true);

$trackid = '7oolFzHipTMg2nL7shhdz2';
$trackidString = 'spotify:track:' . $trackid;

$playcount = null;

// Loop through the discs looking for the track
foreach ($decoded['data']['discs'] as $currDisc)
{
    // If we find the track, get the playcount and break out of the loop
    $key = array_search($trackidString, array_column($currDisc['tracks'], 'uri'));

    if($key !== false)
    {
        $playcount = $currDisc['tracks'][$key]['playcount'];
        break;
    }
}

assert($playcount == 181540969, 'We should find the expected playcount value');

echo 'Result: ' . $playcount . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some inefficient usages of array functions for a task that is cleanest and most performantly performed with classic nested loops.  When searching traversable structures for a solitary qualifying value, it is not best practice to use array functions because they do not permit "short-circuiting" or a `break`/`return`.  In other words, array functions are a poor choice when you do not need to iterate the entire structure.

While traversing your array structure, whenever you encounter indexed keys on a given label, you should implement another `foreach()`.  There are only 2 levels with indexes on your way to the targeted `uri` and `playcount` values, so only 2 `foreach()` loops are needed.  When you find your targeted `uri`, extract the value then break your loop.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tDoHr))

```
$needle = 'spotify:track:7oolFzHipTMg2nL7shhdz2';

foreach ($decoded['data']['discs'] as $disc) {
    foreach ($disc['tracks'] as $track) {
        if ($track['uri'] === $needle) {
            echo $track['playcount'];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```